# Подключение сценария для тегов details и summary

Tags: javascript, html, html5

В учебнике прочитал про новые теги `details` и `summary`, там же написано, чтоб этот пример работал ие7 нужно подключить сценарий

```
var box=document.getElementById("blocks").style.display="none"; 
var box=document.getElementById("blocks").style.display="block";
```

Вот только что-то этот сценарий у меня работать нигде не хочет.

Comment: уберите var box=

Comment: Положите на jsfiddle. Пока не понятно, что за пример.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать при помощи библиотеки `jQuery`. 
Только не знаю в ие7 будет работать или нет, но в остальных браузерах 100%!
Так, в начале в стилях поставь блоку `display: none;` потом скрипт, можешь прописать внутри тега `head`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#blocks').toggle(function(){
            $(this).css('display','block');
        },function(){
            $(this).css('display','none');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: лол, вы из мухи раздули слона, да еще и добавили мусора, да и логику не понимаете. Плохой пример.

Answer (score 0):

наверно кроссбраузерно так

`var doc = window.document || document;
  doc.getElementById("blocks").style.display = 'none';`